# How to get rid of "categories" in url in hexo

Tags: javascript, url, generator, static-site, hexo

In [Hexo](http://hexo.io) I would like to get rid of `categories` in the url. right now it looks like:

`localhost:4000/categories/artists
localhost:4000/categories/projects`

I would like to strip `categories` so that the urls become:

`localhost:4000/artists
localhost:4000/projects`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set `category_dir` variable to an empty string (`""`) in configuration file of your blog (`_config.yml`)

Comment: That works, but what about the page_title in browser-tab, that still shows "categories"... ?